# ElasticSearch date format, Error using strict

Tags: date, indexing, elasticsearch, format, strict

I am trying to use the strict_date formatter within ElasticSearch which is a a formatter for a full date as four digit year, two digit month of year, and two digit day of month: yyyy-MM-dd.

I am using the following code in Marvel:

```
PUT my_strictindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "dob": {
          "type": "strict_date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

{
   "error": "MapperParsingException[mapping [my_type]]; nested: MapperParsingException[No handler for type [strict_date] declared on field [dob]]; ",
   "status": 400
}

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [ES Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)

It should be

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "dob": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "strict_date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have referred to the docs which include the code you posted but how would I go about adding the strict_date to it? @ChintanShah25

Comment: I edited my answer, what version of ES you are using?

Comment: Unfortunately that is still not working for me. I am running v 1.6.2 .. could this be the cause?

Comment: I think It only works in 2.0, It did not work for me on 1.7 and only [2.0 Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) seems to mention `strict` format

Comment: ahhhhh ok! Thank you so much :)